# A way to convert all localization strings to JSON?

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, localization

I'm trying to develop a phonegap plugin for Android that first checks user's default locale, and then grabs the all the strings of that locale and converts it to JSON, and sends it back to JavaScript.

I know how to check the default locale and send stuff back to JavaScript, but the issue is I have no idea how to do the middle part, ie. get the strings that matches the locale and convert them to JSON.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know the locale, you could have your localization strings in files named by the locale. So for example, en_US.strings, would be the en_US file. If you follow that format, you can just usr XHR to load it. If the file itself is a JSON packet of tokens and localizations, then you are pretty much done.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you tried to say but my local strings are meant to be on native side, just following the android localization guidelines.. So they are xml files found in `res/values/...` folders. And I need to convert those strings found in xml to JSON in native side.

Comment: So basically - you need to request the XML and convert it into JavaScript values, correct? If so, you just load the XML via XHR and use JS to parse the XML. You wouldn't convert it to JSON, you would just use it as XML. The Mozilla Dev Network has an article on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: I solved this by creating a really tiny plugin that only returns a Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() from native side, and then sets my JS 'lang' variable to match the JSON language object found in my JS. The reason I wanted language files stay on native side was easier maintenance. Now I have a bunch of JSON objects inside my JS, which could end up hard to maintain. But anyway, thanks for your effort.

Comment: Btw, if you are using PhoneGap, don't forget there is an easier way to get their locale. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getLocaleName

Comment: ohh, didn't know they have included Globalization plugin into PhoneGap 2.2... but looking into to source, the plugin I've implemented does actually just what the Globalization plugin does, and my projects has earlier versions of PhoneGap. Still, good to know! Thanks!